# Reservoir sampling: why is it selected uniformly at random

Tags: algorithm

I understand how the algorithm works. However I don't understand why is it correct. Assume we need to select only one element. Here's the proof that I've found

> at every step N, keep the next element in the stream with probability 1/N. This means that we have an (N-1)/N probability of keeping the element we are currently holding on to, which means that we keep it with probability (1/(N-1)) * (N-1)/N = 1/N.

I understand everything except for the last part. Why do we multiply the probabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Pr[A AND B] == Pr[A] * Pr[B]`, assuming that `A` and `B` are independent (as they are here). The probability of choosing the element AND not replacing it later, is the product of those two possibilities' probabilities.